# Deserializing nested json object with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I would like to ask you guys how to deserialize nested object with jackson.
I got example Json File:

```
{
    "id": "1",              
    "comment": "Some comment",
    "user": "Smith",
    "date": "2018-05-31",
    "shape": "oval",
    "coordinates": [ ["50", "130"], ["370", "500"] ]
},
```

Let's say that main Class is called `Comment`, but I would like to create another class `Coordinates` with local variables `x1, x2, y1, y2`.
So class `Comment` looks like that:

```
 public class CommentFile implements Serializable{
    private Long id;
    private String comment;
    private String user;
    private String date;
    private String shape;
    private Coordinates coordinates;
    //setters, getters, constructor
```

But because in json i have 'array' `"coordinates": [ ["50", "130"], ["370", "500"] ]`, i dont know how to convert this to:

```
public class Coordinates implements Serializable{
private double x1;
private double y1;
private double x2;
private double y2;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward way is to use `List<List<String>> coordinates;`  to deserialize the JSON to Java first. Later, you can implement a method something like `getCoordinatesObject()` inside `CommentFile` class to create and get a Coordinates object.

There might be a better way to accomplish this directly with Jackson but you can do this as well.